# Why Tomcat Memory is not Increasing

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, webserver, tomcat8

The server which Application is installed on it has 1G Memory . But when tomcat start it only   start by 500MB

I have create setenv.sh as below

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms2024m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx3024m"
```

I need to know why it is not staring with 2GB

When i want to start the tomcat use  below  command

```
./catalina.sh start
```

In CATALINA.SH below code is already exits , which will calls the setenv.sh

```
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi
```

I have check tomcat log , it is mentioned that it is start with 2024m but It is still not using the 2G Ram

```
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms2024m
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx3024m
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is tomcat starting in `setenv.sh`? Environment variables are inherited into child processes and will not affect the parent, so the following will not work:

```
$ ./setenvh.sh
$ ./start-tomcat.sh
```

Because the shell is the parent process, the variable gets set in a child process (`setenv.sh`) and then "forgotten" when that script exits.

The following will work:

```
$ . ./setenv.sh
$ ./start-tomcat.sh
```

Because the `.` executes `setenv.sh` in the current shell and modifies your variables before starting tomcat in a child process.

Comment: would you please help me more , I run ./catalonia.sh start  when i want to start , would you please let me know your way of starting tomcat

Comment: I would edit `catalina.sh` with something like `CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms2024m -Xmx3024m"`

Comment: can you add the setenv.sh to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The best way

Run in linux

```
 export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms2024m -Xmx3024m"
```

Stop Start tomcat

```
./catalina.sh stop
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms2024m -Xmx3024
```

when you stop the tomcat in log it mention

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms2024m -Xmx3024
```

Start

```
./catalina.sh start
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

and by below command you can check JAVA environment changed

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

Result

```
 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms2024m -Xmx3024m
         intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
        uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
        uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
        uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 2122317824                          {product}
        uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
        uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 3170893824                          {product}
         intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
         intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
    java version "1.8.0_111"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```